# Stateless component: A valid React element (or null) must be returned

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm new to ReactJS.

I'm trying to display `Hello world` using the code below, but I get this error message:

[image]

What am I missing?

**Code for App.js**

```
//App.js`

import React from 'react';

const App = () => "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";

export default App;
```

**Code for index.js**

```
//index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Code for /public/index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry @FabianSchultz what do you mean?

Comment: Don't use quotes (`""`) around a React element, try it like this: `const App = () => <h1>Hello World!</h1>;`. Either use JSX or `React.createElement`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. It worked!

Comment: The error says it all: *"A valid React element (or null) must be returned"*. You are returning a **string**, which is neither `null` nor a React element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't wrap a JSX element in quotes.

Change this

```
const App = () => "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
```

by this

```
const App = () => <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
```

You can also write it like this

```
const App = () => {    
  return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
};
```

Or like this

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <h1>
      Hello World!
    </h1>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also write it this way and avoid the return statement.

Notice the absence of curly braces, it took me some time to notice they were simple parentheses.

```
const App = () => (
  <h1>
    Hello World !
  </h1>
)
```

Comment: Can't you also avoid the parentheses by condensing the JSX to one line, and moving it all to the same line as the arrow?

Comment: Absolutely, but that won't work if you have more than just one html element. Most components tend to have a little more markup than my example.